# Can not insert multiple videos into a playlist - YouTube API v3

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to add multiple videos to a playlist, but only one video is added to the playlist. I can successful create a playlist and insert a video to the playlist, but can not insert multiple videos to the playlist.

Below is a simple way that I am doing this. The function addTheseVideosToPlaylist() is specifically where I am failing. createPlaylist() and addToPlaylist() are also shown.

There is a global playlistId to keep track of created playlist.

```
var playlistId
```

I create a playlist like this:

```
function createPlaylist() {
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
        part: 'snippet,status',
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                title: 'hard coded title',
                description: 'Hard Coded Description'
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: 'private'
            }
        }
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        var result = response.result;
        if (result) {
            playlistId = result.id;
            console.log("created playlist " + playlistId)
        }
    });
}
```

I add a video to the created playlist given a valid video id like below:

```
function addToPlaylist(id, startPos, endPos) {
    console.log("In addToPlaylist with " + id  +
                "sending to playlist : " + playlistId);

    var details = {
        videoId: id,
        kind: 'youtube#video'
    }

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
        part: 'snippet',
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                playlistId: playlistId,
                resourceId: details
            }
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

The two above functions are fairly standard and work fine. However I have problems when adding multiple videos to a playlist like below in addTheseVideosToPlaylist(). I have an array of valid video ids and for each id, I will add it to the created playlist. The problem is that not all of the videos are added to the playlist, only one video is added.

```
function addTheseVideosToPlaylist() {
    var links = [
        "wtLJPvx7-ys",
        "K3meJyiYWFw",
        "3TtVsy98ces"
    ]
    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        addToPlaylist(links[i]);
}
```

All in all, I am successful in creating a playlist and adding a video to the playlist, but when I try to insert multiple videos to a playlist by adding each link in an array, the playlist only contains one video.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Rohan's answer, the function call at the bottom should be:

```
function myLoop(video_id) {
    addToPlaylist(video_id);
    setTimeout(function() {
        counter++;
        if(counter < links.length)
            myLoop(links[counter]);
    }, 3000);
}
```

It lacked "video_id" as a parameter.

It worked good for me.

The whole, working code is:

```
// Global array holds links and a global counter variable
var links = [
  "wtLJPvx7-ys",
  "K3meJyiYWFw",
  "3TtVsy98ces"
]
var counter = 0;

function addVideosToPlaylist() {
    myLoop(links[0]);
}

function myLoop(video_id) {
    addToPlaylist(video_id);
    setTimeout(function() {
        counter++;
        if(counter < links.length)
            myLoop(links[counter]);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think I now understand why you need to add a delay. You need to delay each insert request before you send the next one.

My solution is recursion. Only when I get a response from the request am I sending the next request till the end of the array:

```
function addVideoToPlayList(pId, videosIdArray, index)
{
    var vId = videosIdArray[index];
    var details = {
        videoId: vId,
        kind: 'youtube#video'
    }

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
        part: 'snippet',
        resource: {
            snippet: {
                playlistId: pId,
                resourceId: details
            }
        }
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        if(videosIdArray.length == index+1)
        {
            // End!
        }
        else{
            addVideoToPlayList(pId,videosIdArray,++index);
        }

        $('#status').html(
            $('#status').html() + '<pre>' +
            JSON.stringify(response.result) + '</pre><br/>');
    });
}
```

Example of how to call this function:

```
addVideoToPlayList(destPlaylistId, videosIdArray, 0);
```

Comment: This is a better solution because the delay required can be dependent on connection speed. Also, if the delay is insufficient, videos end up being added multiple times or skipped

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add delays for every insert into a playlist. I'm not entirely sure why a delay is needed though.

I am using a custom loop too with `setTimeout();`.

Example implementation using delays:

```
// Global array holds links and a global counter variable
var links = [
  "wtLJPvx7-ys",
  "K3meJyiYWFw",
  "3TtVsy98ces"
]
var counter = 0;

function addVideosToPlaylist() {
    myLoop(links[0]);
}


function myLoop() {
    addToPlaylist(video_id);
    setTimeout(function() {
        counter++;
        if (counter < links.length)
            myLoop(links[counter]);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a modern solution

```
/**
 * A recursive function that accepts a single track and makes repeated calls to the endpoint until the response is successful.
 * @param {String} accessToken The Google Auth Access Token required to make POST requests.
 * @param {Object} resourceId The Youtube track to POST into the Youtube playlist.
 * @param {String} playlistId The playlistId of what playlist to POST the tracks to.
 */
const postYoutubeTrack = async (accessToken, singleResourceId, playlistId) => {
  const request = await fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: {
          kind: singleResourceId.kind,
          videoId: singleResourceId.videoId,
        },
      },
    }),
  });

  if (request.ok) {
    const response = await request.json();
    return response;
  }

  postYoutubeTrack(accessToken, singleResourceId, playlistId);
};

export default postYoutubeTrack;
```